# Xamarin XAML vs AXML vs Storyboard

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.ios, storyboard

First of all, I am not even sure if this is a good question, but I am a bit confused with these concepts so I gotta go ahead and ask. Please understand that II have very limited experience with Xamarin.

I've created a project (shared class lib) and I've seen that we create forms with XAML in the shared project. However, I also discovered that there are AXML files in the Android project and Storyboard files in the iOS project, which from what I understand are used to create UI and navigation relations. If I am wrong until here, please correct me.

So the question is, which one should I be using? From what I've experimented with XAML, it is quite easy to create UI's for all platforms but why are those andoroid and ios storyboard things are there then? Or are they completely unrelated from each other?

I am doing this on VS2017 but I've also experimented on Xamarin on Visual Studio for Mac. But primarily my dev environment will be Windows.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards only apply to iOS.  AXML only applies to Android.  XAML is used by Xamarin Forms, which can be used for both Android and iOS (and others).

If you're building a XF project, you will generally want to use XAML, unless there is some platform specific UI you need to create, in which case you (might) use the native Storyboard/AXML approach.